# How to fix callback inside the spider in python scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm creating a web scraper and want to callback to get sub-pages, but it seems not working correctly and no result, any one can help ?

Here is my code

```
class YellSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yell"
    start_urls = [url, ]

    def parse(self, response):
        pageNum = 0
        pages = len(response.xpath(".//div[@class='col-sm-14 col-md-16 col-lg-14 text-center']/*"))
        for page in range(pages):
            pageNum = page + 1
            for x in range(5):
                num = random.randint(5, 8)
            time.sleep(num)
            for item in response.xpath(".//a[@href][contains(@href,'/#view=map')][contains(@href,'/biz/')]"):
                subcategory = base_url + item.xpath("./@href").extract_first().replace("/#view=map", "")
                sub_req = scrapy.Request(subcategory, callback=self.parse_details)
                yield sub_req

        next_page = base_url + "ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=" + classification + "&keywords=" + keyword + "&location=" + city + "&pageNum=" + str(
            pageNum + 1)
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, sub_req):
        for x in range(5):
            num = random.randint(1, 5)
        # time.sleep(num)
        name = sub_req.xpath(".//h1[@class='text-h1 businessCard--businessName']/text()").extract_first()
        address = " ".join(
            sub_req.xpath(".//span[@class='address'][@itemprop='address']/child::node()/text()").extract())
        telephone = sub_req.xpath(".//span[@class='business--telephoneNumber']/text()").extract_first()
        web = sub_req.xpath(
            ".//div[@class='row flexColumns-sm-order-8 floatedColumns-md-right floatedColumns-lg-right floatedColumns-md-19 floatedColumns-lg-19']//a[@itemprop='url']/@href").extract_first()
        hours = ""
        overview = ""
        yield {
            'Name': name,
            'Address': address,
            'Telephone': telephone,
            'Web Site': web
        }
```

I want to callback from `response` to `parse_details`

I expect to loop over all adds in `sub_req` and **scrape** the data from it
and here is the logfile:

```
2019-06-17 15:50:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: Web_Scraper)
2019-06-17 15:50:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.4.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.1, Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
2019-06-17 15:50:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'Web_Scraper', 'LOG_FILE': 'output.log', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Web_Scraper.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Web_Scraper.spiders']}
2019-06-17 15:50:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 91c423015a2cd984
2019-06-17 15:50:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-06-17 15:50:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-06-17 15:50:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-06-17 15:50:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-06-17 15:50:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-06-17 15:50:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-06-17 15:50:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-06-17 15:50:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-06-17 15:50:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1> (referer: None)
2019-06-17 15:50:49 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/pennine-tuition-services-liverpool-9465687> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/pennine-tuition-services-liverpool-9465687/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/pennine-tuition-services-liverpool-9465687>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/home-maths-tutoring-liverpool-7467622/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/home-maths-tutoring-liverpool-7467622>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-wallasey-8945913/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/kumon-maths-and-english-wallasey-8945913>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tution-wallasey-7574939/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/maths-tution-wallasey-7574939>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/patrick-haslam-tutoring-liverpool-8777349/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/patrick-haslam-tutoring-liverpool-8777349>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tution-wallasey-8327361/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/maths-tution-wallasey-8327361>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/dr-john-ankers-science-and-maths-tutor-liverpool-8467525/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/dr-john-ankers-science-and-maths-tutor-liverpool-8467525>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/tutor-services-liverpool-liverpool-8134849/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/tutor-services-liverpool-liverpool-8134849>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/advanced-maths-tutorials-liverpool-3755223/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/advanced-maths-tutorials-liverpool-3755223>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-liverpool-8903743/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/kumon-maths-and-english-liverpool-8903743>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-study-centre-bebington-wirral-7460985/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/kumon-maths-and-english-study-centre-bebington-wirral-7460985>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/pennine-tuition-services-liverpool-9465687/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/north-west-tutors-liverpool-901511208/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/north-west-tutors-liverpool-901511208>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/home-maths-tutoring-liverpool-7467622/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/triple-m-education-prenton-8934754/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/triple-m-education-prenton-8934754>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-wallasey-8945913/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/pennine-tuition-services-liverpool-9465687/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tution-wallasey-7574939/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tuition-wallasey-901339881/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/maths-tuition-wallasey-901339881>
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/dr-john-ankers-science-and-maths-tutor-liverpool-8467525/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/home-maths-tutoring-liverpool-7467622/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/tutor-services-liverpool-liverpool-8134849/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-wallasey-8945913/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/patrick-haslam-tutoring-liverpool-8777349/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tution-wallasey-8327361/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/advanced-maths-tutorials-liverpool-3755223/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tution-wallasey-7574939/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/activett-liverpool-901311152/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/activett-liverpool-901311152>
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-liverpool-8903743/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/dr-john-ankers-science-and-maths-tutor-liverpool-8467525/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=4> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/tutor-services-liverpool-liverpool-8134849/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/liz-beattie-tutoring-prenton-7618961/> from <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/liz-beattie-tutoring-prenton-7618961>
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/askademia-liverpool-8680035> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/patrick-haslam-tutoring-liverpool-8777349/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tution-wallasey-8327361/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-study-centre-bebington-wirral-7460985/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/north-west-tutors-liverpool-901511208/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/advanced-maths-tutorials-liverpool-3755223/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/triple-m-education-prenton-8934754/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/1-2-1-tutoring-liverpool-901224945> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-liverpool-8903743/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tuition-wallasey-901339881/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/dmw-tuition-ltd-liverpool-6887458> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/askademia-liverpool-8680035>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/wallasey-tuition-wallasey-7390339> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/zenitheducators-liverpool-7791342> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/explore-learning-liverpool-901511688> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/kumon-maths-and-english-study-centre-bebington-wirral-7460985/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/north-west-tutors-liverpool-901511208/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/edes-educational-centre-liverpool-8380869> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/triple-m-education-prenton-8934754/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/love2teach-liverpool-liverpool-9678322> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/activett-liverpool-901311152/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/1-2-1-tutoring-liverpool-901224945>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/maths-tuition-wallasey-901339881/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com//biz/guaranteed-grades-liverpool-7368523> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/dmw-tuition-ltd-liverpool-6887458>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/wallasey-tuition-wallasey-7390339>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/biz/liz-beattie-tutoring-prenton-7618961/> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/zenitheducators-liverpool-7791342>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=1> (referer: https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?&selectedClassification=Tutoring&keywords=Math&location=liverpool&pageNum=4)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/explore-learning-liverpool-901511688>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/edes-educational-centre-liverpool-8380869>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/love2teach-liverpool-liverpool-9678322>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/activett-liverpool-901311152/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com//biz/guaranteed-grades-liverpool-7368523>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.yell.com/biz/liz-beattie-tutoring-prenton-7618961/>

{'Name': None, 'Address': '', 'Telephone': None, 'Web Site': None}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 21544,
 'downloader/request_count': 45,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 45,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 257613,
 'downloader/response_count': 45,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 29,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 16,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 51,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 17, 13, 50, 57, 376036),
 'item_scraped_count': 25,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 71,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 29,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 44,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 44,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 44,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 44,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 17, 13, 50, 34, 114473)}
2019-06-17 15:50:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: I added it in the original question